# How to properly convert string into int to calculate in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have this "2+2" and "(2+5)*2" in JS and wanted convert them into int and calculate to get the result of 4 and 14 respectively. So, concerning the research done, I found [convert string to integer and calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962891/convert-string-to-integer-and-calculate) which offers to use eval() which hits performance therefore I wanted to kindly ask what is the right way to convert "2+2" and "(2+5)*2" into int to calculate?

Comment: Other than using `eval` (which you shouldn't for both performance and security reasons), you can only write your own String parser. I'd do neither and make sure I don't have such strings to work with.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you have been given this task? Is it a school assignment?

Comment: Although you can use `eval` for this but it is not a good practice to use eval and it has a lot of security issues unless you are sure your string does consist of operators and digits.
For eval you can use this:

`let calculated = eval('2+2');`

But if not it is better to separate digits and operators via regex and then do the operation.

Comment: @JLRishe, no I was creating calculator in React and wanted to convert that string to something that can be calculated and show the result:)

Comment: @connexo, thank you for your comments, what do you think about math.js. Is it ok to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using eval() correctly in this case as that is what is made for. As per @yckart in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479236/calculate-string-value-in-javascript-not-using-eval), he used the function constructor to evaluate.